# How to sort and pick the latest date for each record

Tags: sql

I am trying to capture the following:

List of patients whose last visit date(Eventdate) has a visit location of Lab.  And I need to pull this data for the past 3 months. 
The below query runs fine, however when I do some QA I see that for some of the patients that show up LAB is not their last visit. What is wrong with my query?

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT
SSKeyField=Event_AntiCoag.SS_Event_AntiCoag_ID, 
SSParentField=A.SS_Patient_ID, 
A.Last_Name, 
A.First_Name, 
A.Patient_ID, 
A.MaxOfEventDate, 
A.VisitLoc,
A.Active

FROM 
(SELECT Demographics.Last_Name, Demographics.First_Name
, Demographics.SS_Patient_ID, Demographics.Patient_ID
, Max(Event_AntiCoag.EventDate) AS MaxOfEventDate
, AntiCoag_Extension.VisitLoc
, Demographics_Extension.Active

FROM ((Event_AntiCoag INNER JOIN Demographics ON Event_AntiCoag.SS_Patient_ID = Demographics.SS_Patient_ID) INNER JOIN AntiCoag_Extension ON Event_AntiCoag.SS_Event_AntiCoag_ID = AntiCoag_Extension.SS_Event_AntiCoag_ID) INNER JOIN Demographics_Extension ON Event_AntiCoag.SS_Patient_ID = Demographics_Extension.SS_Patient_ID

GROUP BY Demographics.Last_Name, Demographics.First_Name, Demographics.SS_Patient_ID
, Demographics.Patient_ID, AntiCoag_Extension.VisitLoc, Demographics_Extension.Active
)A 

INNER JOIN (Event_AntiCoag INNER JOIN AntiCoag_Extension 
ON Event_AntiCoag.SS_Event_AntiCoag_ID = AntiCoag_Extension.SS_Event_AntiCoag_ID) 
ON (A.MaxOfEventDate = Event_AntiCoag.EventDate) 
      AND (A.SS_Patient_ID = Event_AntiCoag.SS_Patient_ID)

WHERE A.Active=1 
     AND ((A.VisitLoc='Lab') AND (A.MaxOfEventDate >= '4/1/2013')) 
    ORDER BY A.Last_Name, A.First_Name
```

Comment: I do not know your data structure sufficiently, but the `Max(Event_AntiCoag.EventDate)` seems to be taken for each group of identically valued `Demographics.Last_Name, Demographics.First_Name, Demographics.SS_Patient_ID, Demographics.Patient_ID, AntiCoag_Extension.VisitLoc` and `Demographics_Extension.Active`. Is this really necessary to have that many values be the same? In case of one of those values being different between two visits you will get two groups and the max-value will not really be the max value.

Comment: Your code is hard to read, but it appears that you are looking for `A.VisitLoc` yet are selecting `MAX(Event_AntiCoag.EventDate)`. How are you ascertaining that there are no visits after the last lab visit?